# Finding the sum of the product of factorials of the digits of numbers

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory

I want to calculate the sum of the product of factorials of the digits of numbers. So for example, when $n=467$ I get:

$$n=467\space\to\space\left(4!\right)\cdot\left(6!\right)\cdot\left(7!\right)=87091200\space\to\space8+7+0+9+1+2+0+0=27\tag1$$

So, when $n=467$ I must get $27$.

How can I write fast code to do that? Thanks in advance and Merry Christmas to everybody.

I wrote the following code:

```
Total@
  IntegerDigits[
    Product[
      Factorial[Part[IntegerDigits[n], k]],
      {k, 1, Length[IntegerDigits[n]]}
    ]
  ]
```

Which does the job but is really slow.

Comment: This may be slightly faster: `f[n_] := Total@IntegerDigits[Times @@ Map[Factorial, IntegerDigits[n]]]` by using `Times` instead of `Product`

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks, I am testing it right now.

Comment: When you have a multicore computer you could try to wrap parallelize arround it.

Comment: @oyy I have 64 cores

Comment: I don't think there's a point to parallelization here. There are only ten possible factorials (digits 0 through 9), and you can just memoize those and look them up.

Comment: A little more compact is `f[n_] := Total@IntegerDigits[Times @@ Factorial[IntegerDigits[n]]]`.

Comment: Carl's suggestion to memoize the factorials for the digits seems to give a small speedup (~10%) over bbgodfrey's formula directly. Fairly small improvement, might vary between machines. `facts = Factorial[Range[10] - 1]; f[n_] := Total@IntegerDigits[Times @@ facts[[IntegerDigits[n] + 1]]]`

Comment: Try this one liner: `Composition[Total, IntegerDigits, Times @@ # &, Factorial, 
  IntegerDigits][n]`

Comment: All solutions given in the comments require about ten seconds on my computer to process a ten-million-digit number.  The solution in the question is much slower.